# Badge added to treeview item is clipped

Tags: vuetify.js

Here is the snippet from the template for my view:

```
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-treeview selectable hoverable :items="items" :open.sync="open">
              <template v-slot:prepend="{ item }">
                <v-icon>{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
              </template>
              <template v-slot:label="{ item }">
                <v-badge :content="item.count">{{item.name}}</v-badge>
              </template>
            </v-treeview>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
```

The badge is clipped vertically.

Is there a way to prevent clipping?

Answer (score 1):

Found an easy solution. Add the following to the vue file.

```
<style lang="scss">
.v-treeview-node__content {
  line-height: 4;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-badge :content="item.count" inline>{{item.name}}</v-badge>
```

Adding `inline` prop to `v-badge` solves the problem. Please have a look [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/badges/#badges).

Comment: Thank you @jet_choong for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it renders the badge in. the same line as the text. This solution did not work for my requirement. Adjusting line-height fixes the rendering of badge.